# Firebase Authentication operations in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase

When I check the user it always turns data on checkUserAuth() function and isLogin is true .Then  When I push the logout button, isLogin becomes false instantly and becomes true again.How to use checkUserAuth function??
Thank you for any assistance

```
//Navbar.jsx

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

import Firebase from "../firebase/firebase.utils";

const Navbar = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    Firebase.checkUserAuth().then((user) => {
      if (user) {
        setIsLogin(true);
      }
    });
  }, [isLogin]);

  const logout = () => {
    if (isLogin === true) {
      Firebase.signOut().then(() => {
        setIsLogin(false);
        history.push("/");
      });
      
    }
  };
```

```
///Firebase

const Firebase = {
  // auth
  loginWithEmail: async (email, password) => {
    return await firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  },
  signupWithEmail: async (email, password) => {
    return await firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  },
  signOut: async () => {
    return await firebase.auth().signOut()
    .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
  },
  checkUserAuth: async () => {
    return await firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(data => data);
  },

  // firestore
  createNewUser: (userData) => {
    return firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(`${userData.uid}`)
      .set(userData);
  },
};

export default Firebase;
```

Comment: This might be because `onAuthStateChanged` is an event listener and gets called whenever there is an auth change.

Comment: I don't fully understand. What should i try. Because returns data in all cases